# passing codeigniter data to simple html dom url variable

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, parsing, simple-html-dom

I have a problem. I would like to pass my Codeigniter Mysql variables (which I can use at the template as `{{ category:country }}` using this library http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ ) at a simple HTML-DOM URL variable. I tried lot of variation without result.

Here is the beginning of my code:

```
<?php

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$url = 'http://address.com/".{{ category:country }}."/'; 

?>
```

I would like to open the address, like if I got the germany variable, then parse this: `http://address.com/germany` .

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Try it like this; `"http://address.com/{{category:country}}"`

Comment: I tried like this, I got this error message: Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Comment: What does `simple_html_dom.php` contain? Where is `category:country` coming from? What CodeIgniter version are you using? According to the [docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html) you might be using the syntax incorrectly. What templating engine are you trying to use?

Comment: simple html dom is the library of the parser. I think you already hear about simple html dom. This is pyrocms 2.2, and this is the template php which display the blog content.

Comment: I would like to display specified parsed content in my blog view.php.

Comment: I see, so is this line failing? `$url = 'http://address.com/".{{ category:country }}."/';`. If it is failing then try debugging by doing `echo 'http://address.com/".{{ category:country }}."/';`

Comment: I got this result after put the row with echo:  http://address.com/".Norway."/

Comment: If I put this:      `echo 'http://address.com/{{ category:country }}/';   `     then the result is this: http://address.com/Norway/

Comment: but if I use this formula at the url then it is not good for simple html dom... I got error message about fatal error Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Comment: I think I understand now, I will have an answer for you shortly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue correctly then what you want might be tricky or impossible.

Basically, Simply HTML DOM is working with code in memory so when you feed it `$url` then it is trying to visit a URL named `http://address.com/".{{ category:country }}."/`

The template parser acts upon PHP's output buffer so it's not invoked until it is ready to call all the [ob_* functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

If your templating engine supports it then you will need to do something like this:

```
<?php

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url = 'http://address.com/".{{ category:country }}."/'; 

// Find a function which will parse the string you have passed into it
$url = FAKE_FUNCTION_templating_engine_PARSE_NOW($url);

// At this point, Simple HTML DOM will be able to properly use the $url

?>
```

Comment: Not supported:( Fatal error: Call to undefined function templating_engine_PARSE_NOW()

Comment: @Liverpool_FC correct, that function does not exist. YOU have to do some research and see if your templating engine has a function like this...

Comment: But I don't understand. Because I could add date variables (like today, yesterday) to the url address of simple html dom. It is impossible to pass mysql variables to simple html dom url address?

Comment: @Liverpool_FC Looks like I have misunderstood something. You will have to solve the error you mentioned earlier: `Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object`

Comment: @Liverpool_FC Yes, `date('Y')` is executed as soon as it is read by the compiler; before the output buffer is called.

Comment: And if I integrate the simple html dom library into the codeigniter engine? Like this: http://thephpx.com/2009/10/php-simple-html-dom-parser-codeigniter-integration/

Comment: without the integration with normal url address there is no problem, parsing successful.

Comment: @Liverpool_FC You will still have the same issue. The templating engine is invoked upon output buffering, not during the course of PHP compilation and regular code execution.

Comment: so this is impossible

Comment: @Liverpool_FC Have you tried looking for a function from your templating engine which will parse a string for you on command like I suggested?

Comment: so I must search a function which enable parse strings, right?

Comment: @Liverpool_FC Correct, you're welcome, and good luck. Let me know how your searching goes. If you find something of interest but aren't sure how to use it then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

But there is a built-in parser in pyrocms:

Here is the code:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * CodeIgniter Dwoo Parser Class
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Libraries
 * @category    Parser
 * @license  http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/dbad-license
 * @link        http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-dwoo
 */

class MY_Parser extends CI_Parser {

    private $_ci;

    public function __construct($config = array())
    {
        $this->_ci = & get_instance();

        if ( ! class_exists('Lex_Autoloader'))
        {
            include APPPATH.'/libraries/Lex/Autoloader.php';
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     *  Parse a view file
     *
     * Parses pseudo-variables contained in the specified template,
     * replacing them with the data in the second param
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @param   array
     * @param   bool
     * @return  string
     */
    public function parse($template, $data = array(), $return = false, $is_include = false, $streams_parse = array())
    {
        $string = $this->_ci->load->view($template, $data, true);

        return $this->_parse($string, $data, $return, $is_include, $streams_parse);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     *  String parse
     *
     * Parses pseudo-variables contained in the string content,
     * replacing them with the data in the second param
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @param   array
     * @param   bool
     * @return  string
     */
    public function parse_string($string, $data = array(), $return = false, $is_include = false, $streams_parse = array())
    {
        return $this->_parse($string, $data, $return, $is_include, $streams_parse);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     *  Parse
     *
     * Parses pseudo-variables contained in the specified template,
     * replacing them with the data in the second param
     *
     * @access  protected
     * @param   string
     * @param   array
     * @param   bool
     * @return  string
     */
    protected function _parse($string, $data, $return = false, $is_include = false, $streams_parse = array())
    {
        // Start benchmark
        $this->_ci->benchmark->mark('parse_start');

        // Convert from object to array
        is_array($data) or $data = (array) $data;

        $data = array_merge($data, $this->_ci->load->_ci_cached_vars);

        Lex_Autoloader::register();

        if ($streams_parse and isset($streams_parse['stream']) and isset($streams_parse['namespace']))
        {
            // In some very rare cases (mainly in the pages module), we need to
            // change the field that is being passed to plugin_override() as row_id.
            // This is where that happens.
            $id_name = (isset($streams_parse['id_name']) and $streams_parse['id_name']) ? $streams_parse['id_name'] : 'id';

            $this->_ci->load->driver('Streams');
            $parsed = $this->_ci->streams->parse->parse_tag_content($string, $data, $streams_parse['stream'], $streams_parse['namespace'], false, null, $id_name);
        }
        else
        {
            $parser = new Lex_Parser();
            $parser->scope_glue(':');
            $parser->cumulative_noparse(true);
            $parsed = $parser->parse($string, $data, array($this, 'parser_callback'));
        }

        // Finish benchmark
        $this->_ci->benchmark->mark('parse_end');

        // Return results or not ?
        if ( ! $return)
        {
            $this->_ci->output->append_output($parsed);
            return;
        }

        return $parsed;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Callback from template parser
     *
     * @param   array
     * @return   mixed
     */
    public function parser_callback($plugin, $attributes, $content)
    {
        $this->_ci->load->library('plugins');

        $return_data = $this->_ci->plugins->locate($plugin, $attributes, $content);

        if (is_array($return_data) && $return_data)
        {
            if ( ! $this->_is_multi($return_data))
            {
                $return_data = $this->_make_multi($return_data);
            }

            // $content = $data['content']; # TODO What was this doing other than throw warnings in 2.0?
            $parsed_return = '';

            $parser = new Lex_Parser();
            $parser->scope_glue(':');

            foreach ($return_data as $result)
            {
                // if ($data['skip_content'])
                // {
                //  $simpletags->set_skip_content($data['skip_content']);
                // }

                $parsed_return .= $parser->parse($content, $result, array($this, 'parser_callback'));
            }

            unset($parser);

            $return_data = $parsed_return;
        }

        return $return_data ? $return_data : null;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Ensure we have a multi array
     *
     * @param   array
     * @return   int
     */
    private function _is_multi($array)
    {
        return (count($array) != count($array, 1));
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Forces a standard array in multidimensional.
     *
     * @param   array
     * @param   int     Used for recursion
     * @return  array   The multi array
     */
    private function _make_multi($flat, $i=0)
    {
        $multi = array();
        $return = array();
        foreach ($flat as $item => $value)
        {
            if (is_object($value))
            {
                $return[$item] = (array) $value;
            }
            else
            {
                $return[$i][$item] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }
}

// END MY_Parser Class

/* End of file MY_Parser.php */
```